# 2D array data being overwritten?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have basic code which creates a two dimensional array of an object which holds x and y. When I first instantiate the objects within the array, the data they hold is accurate. But when I get inside a requestAnimationFrame loop the data becomes corrupted and it's no longer accurate?
And I can't explain why it's happening

Here's my index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    class Pos {
        constructor(y, x) {
            this.y = y;
            this.x = x;
        }
        getx() {
            return x;
        }
        gety() {
            return y;
        }
    }
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    let surfacex = 10;
    let surfacey = 10;
    let surface = new Array(surfacey);

    for (var y = 0; y < surfacey; ++y) {
        surface[y] = new Array(surfacex);
    }
    for (var y = 0; y < surfacey; ++y) {
        for (var x = 0; x < surfacex; ++x) {
            surface[y][x] = new Pos(y, x);
        }
    }

    for (var y = 0; y < surfacey; ++y) {
        for (var x = 0; x < surfacex; ++x) {
            console.log(surface[y][x].getx()+":"+surface[y][x].gety());//THis line prints correctly
        }
    }

    function tick(time) {


        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, surfacex, surfacey);

       for (var y = 0; y < surfacey; ++y) {
        for (var x = 0; x < surfacex; ++x) {
            console.log(surface[y][x].getx()+":"+surface[y][x].gety());//Prints 10:10....no longer correct
        }
    }

        requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(tick);
});
```

I run a 2D loop to instantiate then objects, then run the loop again to print their data. Their data gets printed correctly but when I run the loop consecutively inside requestAnimationFrame loop, the getx and gety just keep returning 10:10..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `getx()` and `gety()` methods, you should refer to `x` and `y` as `this.x` and `this.y`:

```
class Pos {
  constructor(y, x) {
    this.y = y;
    this.x = x;
  }
  getx() {
    return this.x;
  }
  gety() {
    return this.y;
  }
}
```

Variables declared using `var` in Javascript will be 'hoisted'. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) for more information on this. Basically it means that if the variable is referenced before it's declared, then you won't get an error, but the variable is accessible (as `undefined` initially). So the `x` and `y` variables in the `getx()` and `gety()` methods refer to the `x` and `y` variables you're using in your loops. By the time you're executing these methods, you've ran through your loops and the values of `x` and `y` will both be `10`, which get returned by the class methods.

Comment: I"m actually so dumb because I knew this. I can't believe I missed "this." when writing the code. Thank you though. I'm glad it was nothing worse than that.